# (Hill cypher) Python code only decrypts messages with an even number of characters

Tags: python, arrays, math, encryption, linear-algebra

Here is the code:

```
cypherText = "187 211 40 45 305 345 168 189 103 116 195 220 144 162"
cypher = cypherText.split(" ")

print(cypher)
key = []
d = 0
l = len(cypher)

encoded = []

for i in range(0,l,2):
    row = []
    for j in range(1):
        row.append(int(cypher[i]))
        if i < l:
            row.append(cypher[i+1])
    encoded.append(row)

print(encoded)

keys = []
invMatrices = []
for w in range(1,8,1):
    for x in range(1,8,1):
        for y in range(1,8,1):
            for z in range(1,8,1):
                row = [w,x,y,z]
                if (w*z - y*x) != 0:
                    keys.append(row)
                    #d = 1/(w*z - y*x)
                    
                    #inv = [d*z,-d*x,-d*y,d*w]
                    #invMatrices.append(inv)

for i in range(len(keys)):
    
    currentKey = keys[i]

    d = 1/(currentKey[0]*currentKey[3] - currentKey[2]*currentKey[1])

    inv = [d*currentKey[3],-d*currentKey[1],-d*currentKey[2],d*currentKey[0]]

    invMatrices.append(inv)





finalDecoded = []

for i in range(len(invMatrices)):
    decoded = []  # Initialize an empty list for each iteration
    for j in range(len(encoded)):
        row = []
        num1 = (float(encoded[j][0]) * invMatrices[i][0]) + (float(encoded[j][1]) * invMatrices[i][2])
        num2 = (float(encoded[j][0]) * invMatrices[i][1]) + (float(encoded[j][1]) * invMatrices[i][3])
        row.append(num1)
        row.append(num2)
        decoded.append(row)

    finalDecoded.append(decoded)

print("Final decoded")
print(finalDecoded)
print("\n\n\n")




# Initialize an empty list to store the sorted results
sortedList = []

possibleKeys = []

# Loop through each sublist in the 3D list
for i in range(len(finalDecoded)):
    # Initialize an empty list to store the filtered results
    filteredList = []

    # Loop through each item in the sublist
    for j in range(len(finalDecoded[i])):

        filteredList1 = []

        for k in range(len(finalDecoded[i][j])):
            
            # Check if the item is a whole number
            if finalDecoded[i][j][k] == int(finalDecoded[i][j][k]) and finalDecoded[i][j][k] >= 0 and finalDecoded[i][j][k] <= 26:
        
                # If it is a whole number, add it to the filtered list
                filteredList1.append(int(finalDecoded[i][j][k]))

            # Check if the filtered list has two elements
            if len(filteredList1) == 2:

                    # If it does, add it to the filtered list
                    filteredList.append(filteredList1)

    print(filteredList)
    # If the filtered list is not empty, add it to the sorted list
    if len(filteredList) == len(encoded):

        sortedList.append(filteredList)



print("sorted List:")
print(sortedList)

Alphabet = [" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
possibilities = []


for i in range(len(sortedList)):
    row = []

    for j in range(len(sortedList[i])):

        for k in range(len(sortedList[i][j])):


            row.append([Alphabet[sortedList[i][j][k]]])
    possibilities.append(row)

print("\n\n\n")

print(possibilities)
```

Im trying to decode a message given to me using a hill cypher based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrxzWNTtF68, ive been given the information that the key is a 2x2 matrix with values between 1 and 7

Ive been at this for a couple weeks now and any help at all would be much appreciated!! thank you!!!!

The code seems to work until you start trying to decode messages that have an odd number of characters. The encryption algorithm is supposed to encode these by adding an extra space to the end of the message to make it even (spaces are represented by 0 btw).

For some reason, the code ends up producing a list that is not long enough to be equal to the length of the encoded list which does not satisfy the condition in this line:  `if len(filteredList) == len(encoded):`, meaning that the code outputs an empty list

my assumption is that its something to do with my arithmetic because I have not learned anything about linear algebra yet lol, but then why does it work with even numbers of characters?